# Find all files in .txt format Except files that start with Dev

Tags: bash

Find all files in .txt format Except files that start with Dev(for example DevExample.txt)

```
find . -regex '^.*Dev.*\.txt$' -print0)
```

I have such code now, but I want find all .txt EXCEPT with start name Dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -name "*.txt" | grep -v Dev
```

Comment: This will also ignore if name contains some thing like ab-dev.txt

Comment: No, because it is case-sensitive so a lower case "d" will be accepted.

Comment: but what if ab-Dev.txt

Comment: Unlikely... But to cover this the find search term and then grep -v \/Dev ... or better ..... grep -v '\/Dev.*\.txt$' .... For the last one to work it must be single quotes and must include the quotes around the grep search term.

Answer (score 0):

Only with find :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' ! -name 'Dev*'
```